# Ruby how to return an element of a dictionary?

Tags: ruby, hash, element

```
@ dictionary = {"cat"=>"Sam"}
```

This a return a key

```
@dictionary.key(x)
```

This returns a value

```
@dictionary[x]
```

How do I return the entire element 
"cat"=>"Sam"

Comment: We call it a Hash in Ruby, not a dictionary.

Comment: `"cat"=>"Sam"` is a pair, i.e. two elements `"cat"` and `"Sam"`. It cannot be returned as a single object.

Answer (score 1):

```
@dictionary
```

should do the trick for you

whatever is the last evaluated expression in ruby is the return value of a method.
If you want to return the hash as a whole. the last line of the method should look like the line I have written above

Comment: @dictionary will return the whole dictionary? I just want to return 1 element

Comment: you dont understand it sir, `@dictionary = {"cat"=>"Sam"}` line means tht there is an instance variable called `@dictionary` which is a hash and has a value `{"cat"=>"Sam"}`

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to return one element of a hash `h`, you will need to specify the key to identify the element.  As the value for key `k` is `h[k]`, the key-value pair, expressed as an array, is `[k, h[k]]`.  If you wish to make that a hash with a single element, use `Hash[[[k, h[k]]]]`.

For example, if

```
h = { "cat"=>"Sam", "dog"=>"Diva" }
```

and you only wanted to the element with key `"cat"`, that would be

```
["cat", h["cat"]]         #=> ["cat", "Sam"]
```

or

```
Hash[[["cat", h["cat"]]]] #=> {"cat"=>"Sam"}
```

With Ruby 2.1 you could alternatively get the hash like this:

```
[["cat", h["cat"]]].to_h  #=> {"cat"=>"Sam"}
```

Let's look at a little more interesting case.  Suppose you have an array `arr` containing some or all of the keys of a hash `h`.  Then you can get all the key-value pairs for those keys by using the methods [Enumerable#zip](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-zip) and [Hash#values_at](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-values_at):

```
arr.zip(arr.values_at(*arr))
```

Suppose, for example,

```
h = { "cat"=>"Sam", "dog"=>"Diva", "pig"=>"Petunia", "owl"=>"Einstein" }
```

and

```
arr = ["dog", "owl"]
```

Then:

```
arr.zip(h.values_at(*arr))
  #=> [["dog", "Diva"], ["owl", "Einstein"]]
```

In steps:

```
a = h.values_at(*arr)
  #=> h.values_at(*["dog", "owl"])
  #=> h.values_at("dog", "owl")
  #=> ["Diva", "Einstein"]
arr.zip(a)
  #=> [["dog", "Diva"], ["owl", "Einstein"]]
```

To instead express as a hash:

```
Hash[arr.zip(h.values_at(*arr))]
  #=> {"dog"=>"Diva", "owl"=>"Einstein"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example is **a bit** (?) misleading in a sense it only has one pair (while not necessarily), and you want to get one pair. What you call a "dictionary" is actually a hashmap (called a **hash** among Rubyists).

**A hashrocket (`=>`) is a part of hash definition syntax. It can't be used outside it.** That is, you can't get just one pair without constructing a new hash. So, a new such pair would look as: `{ key => value }`.

So in order to do that, you'll need a key and a value in context of your code somewhere. And you've specified ways to get both if you have one. If you only have a value, then:

```
{ @dictionary.key(x) => x }
```

...and if just a key, then:

```
{ x => @dictionary[x] }
```

...but there is no practical need for this. If you want to process each pair in a hash, use an iterator to feed each pair into some code as an argument list:

```
@dictionary.each do |key, value|
  # do stuff with key and value  
end
```

This way a block of code will get each pair in a hash **once**.

If you want to get not a hash, but pairs of elements it's constructed of, you can convert your hash to an array:

```
@dictionary.to_a
# => [["cat", "Sam"]]
# Note the double braces! And see below.
# Let's say we have this:
@dictionary2 = { 1 => 2, 3 => 4}
@dictionary2[1]
# => 2
@dictionary2.to_a
# => [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
# Now double braces make sense, huh?
```

It returns an array of pairs (which are arrays as well) of all elements (keys and values) that your hashmap contains.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the key and value in one go - resulting in an array:

```
@h = {"cat"=>"Sam", "dog"=>"Phil"}
key, value = p h.assoc("cat") # => ["cat", "Sam"]
```

Use `rassoc` to search by value ( `.rassoc("Sam")` )